# Mock (Moq) with unity container and generics

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq, unity-container

I have a Container interface with a generic resolve method which, when implemented, resolves using Unity.

```
public interface IContainer
{
    T Resolve<T>();
}
```

Currently there is a Mock Container class:

```
public class MockContainer : IContainer {
    public T Resolve<T>()
    {            
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

But I want to use Moq for consistency and do the equivalent:

```
mockContainer
    .Setup(container => container.Resolve<T>())
    .Returns(default(T));
```

But I get 2 compile errors `'T' could not be found`

Is the Moq syntax wrong, am I missing a reference or can this just not be done?

**Edit**
I know that mocking the container is not ideal. I could resolve each class one-by-one in my setup code.

My question is whether there is some Moq syntax to perform the equivalent of my actual container.

Comment: I think a fair question would be : why do you need to mock the Resolve anyway, don't you use Dependency Injection?

Answer (score 1):

You usually can't do this (set up generic methods without specifying a type), but if you only want to return `default(T)` and don't care if the function is called at all, it's enough to simply create the mock without calling `Setup`:

```
var mockZincContainer = new Mock<IContainer>();

// works just fine
mockZincContainer.Object.Resolve<DateTime>(); // returns default(DateTime)
mockZincContainer.Object.Resolve<object>(); // returns default(object)
```

You can even return mocks instead of `default(T)` by changing the `DefaultValue` property of the mock from `DefaultValue.Empty` to `DefaultValue.Mock`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to derive a mock object from your interface. So get rid of MockContainer.

In your unit test you should at that point know what types you want to test. So at that point, just give it a real type and tell it what to return.

i.e.

```
//arrange
mockZincContainer
    .Setup(container => container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>())
    .Returns(new ConcreteClassThatDerivesFromSomeInterface());
var testClass = new ClassToBeTested(mockZincContainer.Object);

//act
testClass.DoYourMethod();

//assert
mockZincContainer.Verify(c => c.Resolve<ISomeInterface>(), Times.Once);
```

Comment: unfortunately these unit tests are integration tests and it takes time and is error prone to write these setup and return for every dependency that is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you mock the container?  This is more of an integration concern.  All of your code should be testable without having a container wire them up.   Mocking the container to return a dependency which you are then passing in to consuming classes seems like a big waste of time to me.

Comment: Ideally yes. In reality the unit tests are integration tests and I don't have the freedom to rewrite ~50,000 unit tests